# How do I move the mouse cursor when a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, events, mouse

What do I put in my onkeydown to move the mouse to a specified [x,y]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nothing. you don't get to control the mouse from javascript.

however, you may be able to simulate the action you're looking for.

[Simulating click with javascript on document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890921/simulating-click-with-javascript-on-document)

Answer (score 1):

Seriously?  You want to move *my* mouse pointer without my permission?  Get real!  You can imagine how such capabilities could be used for malicious purposes.